# Regex in Python: extract a multiline part from a text with repeating similar editions

Tags: python, regex, multiline

Thanks in advance for the help. I am using Python regular expressions to extract a part from a text which has the following layout:

```
(A lot of information)

time:    150

C-FXY

-- information ---

E-END

(A lot of information)

time:   5000

C-FXY

**--- INFORMATION I WANT TO EXTRACT ---**

E-END

(A lot of information)

time:  13000

C-FXY

-- information ---

E-END

(A lot of information)
```

I need to extract everything between C-FXY and E-END from the time step corresponding to 5000. For that I am using the following Python 3.6 sentence:

```
time_step = '5000'
text_part = re.search(r'time.*'+time_step+'.*C-FXY(.*?)E-END', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

Unfortunately what I am getting on the output is that same edition between C-FXY and E-END but from the 13000 time step of the text, not the one I want from time: 5000.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using the following code:

```
import re

text = """(A lot of information)

time:    150

C-FXY

-- information ---

E-END

(A lot of information)

time:   5000

C-FXY

**--- INFORMATION I WANT TO EXTRACT ---**

E-END

(A lot of information)

time:  13000

C-FXY

-- information ---

E-END

(A lot of information)"""

pattern = re.compile(r"C-FXY(.*?)E-END")

results = re.findall(r"C-FXY(.*?)E-END", text, re.DOTALL)
```

Now, if you print the `results`:

```
for i, r in enumerate(results):
    print(f"Resultado {i}:\n'{r}'")
```

The output would be:

```
Resultado 0:
'

-- information ---

'
Resultado 1:
'

**--- INFORMATION I WANT TO EXTRACT ---**

'
Resultado 2:
'

-- information ---

'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because your regex contains a *greedy* `.*` between the `time` part and the `C-FXY` one. So it eats everything up to the last group.

It should be enough to use a non greedy version here:

```
text_part = re.search(r'time.*'+time_step+'.*?C-FXY(.*?)E-END', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

Anyway, I would not use a multiline search of the whole file here, but I would just read the file line by line up to the `time:    5000`, then up to the `C-FXY` one, store anything from there up to a `C-END` one, and end processing there.

Comment: Still not getting good results for it. The thing is I wanted to use a regular expression similar to the one that would be used in PERL, just marking the start and end of the information you want to extract.

Although the second way you propose is also valid and I thought about it, I just wanted to explore the possibility of doing it in a sigle sentence with Regex.